# Pausing background gifs/videos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve been playing around with html, css and JS lately. Right now I have a div that has a background gif. This is what I did:

```
<div class = "mydiv" style = "background-image: url(play.gif);"></div>
```

So first, it fills the entire space by repeating the image over and over side by side. I was wondering if there was a way to only have the image show up once and at the center of the div.

Another question I have is if it is possible to “pause” the gif at the beginning and only play it when the user hovers over the div and when they hover-off the gif goes back and stays at the beginning. If this is not possible for gifs, is it possible for videos (.mp4 .webm etc.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: can you put your code JSFIDDLE.It will help to suggest the best proficient answer.!

Comment: No this is not possible with an actual background image. The image would need to be inline.

Comment: @4castle: "was a way to only haev the image show up once and at the center of the div".

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't have much code. All i really have is that html and some css to align everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the first part of your question, yes you can have it show up once in the center. Here is an example.

```css
.mydiv{width:100%;
      height:100vh;
  background-image:url(http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Birds/Penguins/animated-penguin-gif-5.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
```

Comment: you can of course adjust the width/height as required

Comment: to 2nd part of question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473117/animating-a-gif-on-hover

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644209/play-gif-on-mouseover-and-pause-gif-on-mouse-out-without-replacing-images

Comment: Dunno about the play once, but you can 'freeze' the animation like so http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/33Sqd/15/ - i haven't coded the resume

Comment: you could always just create the gif without the loop option in the first place, that would solve your problem.. if its one that's ready-made, it can probably be adjusted in Adobe Fireworks

Comment: Note the `vh` is CSS3 and your mileage may vary on the use of the viewport units. "vh - 1/100th of the height of the viewport."  Note issue mainly on older browsers/mobile.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i made a point of remarking "adjust width/height as required" .. i don't know the size of his div.

Comment: Yep, I noted that +1 anyway due to the good comments you made :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
.mydiv {
    background-image: url(static.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.mydiv:hover {
    background-image: url(play.gif);
}
```

where `static.gif` would be just the first frame from your gif.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to make the gif play only once as well?

Comment: @AllenHuang Not with css, no. It can be done with javascript, but requires quite a bit more work.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could add how to do that to your post?